# how can I setting background show full screen?

Tags: ios, swift

how can I setting background show full screen?

when I used this code, I can set full screen

```
private let usernameEmailField: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "email"
        field.returnKeyType = .next
        field.leftViewMode = .always
        field.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 10, height: 0))
        field.autocapitalizationType = .none
        field.autocorrectionType = .no
        field.layer.masksToBounds = true
        field.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.cornerRadius
        field.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.secondaryLabel.cgColor
        return field
    }()

private let headerView: UIView = {
    let header = UIView()
    header.clipsToBounds = true
    let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "camping_background"))
    header.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
    return header
}()

headerView.frame = CGRect(
    x: 0,
    y: 0.0,
    width: view.width,
    height: view.height
)
usernameEmailField.frame = CGRect(
    x: 25,
    y: headerView.botoom + 10,
    width: view.width - 50,
    height: 52.0
)
```

But if I set `height: view.height` I can not show my textfield. so how do I modify?

```
headerView.frame = CGRect(
    x: 0,
    y: 0.0,
    width: view.width,
    height: view.height
)

usernameEmailField.frame = CGRect(
    x: 25,
    y: headerView.botoom + 10,
    width: view.width - 50,
    height: 52.0
)

passwordField.frame = CGRect(
    x: 25,
    y: usernameEmailField.botoom + 10,
    width: view.width - 50,
    height: 52.0
)
```

if I used `height: view.height/3.0`, if can show textfield, but the background is not fullscreen

[image]

I hope I can show like this one, this is my android page.

[image]

so, if I don't use the storyboard, how can I design in the my LoginViewController

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the code here:

```
headerView.addSubview(backgroundImageView)

...

headerView.botoom + 10,
```

You are stacking your views and the background vertically!

#### But

You should set the image behind the textfields (instead of above them)

Here is the how your view hierarchy could be looks like:

```
- Main View
    - Main Content 
        - Logo image view
        - User name text field
        - Password text field
        - Login button
        - Create account button
    - Background image view
```

As you can see, the `Background image view` is below the other contents

<sub>Note that it's not necessary to group content to layout your view but its very useful method for separating components</sub>

Comment: how can modify it? because I'm a beginner